# win32com Analog to Performing Select All Twice in Excel

Tags: python, excel, formatting, copy-paste, win32com

In win32com,

```
cells = worksheet.UsedRange
```

is similar to pressing cntl-a a single time in Excel.

What is the win32com equivalent to doing cntl-a twice?

> The use case is when you use the format painter after pressing cntl-a twice it will paste all the formatting including the column width.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this. The `.UsedRange` as Excel sees it could easily becomes the entire worksheet (1048576 rows × 16384 columns). The [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) has options for pasting formatting as well as column widths (e.g. `xlPasteColumnWidths`) that is more appropriate.

Comment: If you write this up as an answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this. The [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) as Excel sees it could easily becomes the entire worksheet (1048576 rows × 16384 columns). The [Range.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) method has options for pasting formatting as well as column widths (e.g. [xlPasteColumnWidths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx)) that is more appropriate.

Working with newer worksheets in native Excel, the old rogue [xlCellTypeLastCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) has largely been eliminated but it is still something to be careful about when dealing with cross-platform coding.